# Ganeti KVM settings

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ganeti

When I have played with KVM using libvirtd/virsh, I disabled  section in libvirt's xml configs for VMs an this gives me CPU usage from 7-8% in idle mode per VM to 1-2% for windows guests. This was a great advantage. But how to apply such trick when using Ganeti?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for disturbing the society, have found answer myself, when explored Ganeti's sources. If someone interested, just modify an instance:

```
gnt-instance modify -H vnc_bind_address= <VM_name>
gnt-instance modify -H mouse_type= <VM_name>
```

When mouse_type is empty, it doesn't add "-usb" option to KVM. vnc_bind_address should be empty too, otherwise it adds -usbdevice tablet. CPU usage in idle mode changed from ~7% to ~1%.

Comment: One must emphasize that the spacing is important with these commands.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you submit a bug on their tracker so they could possibly do that by default in a future release.